# Xcode 5 Tab Bar disappearing when reload the page

Tags: xcode, uiviewcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

My second tab has a game list for current week. When I press Next or Previous, It changes to next or previous week game lists. My problem is, when I press next or previous button, Tab bar is disappearing. How can I hold tab bar on the screen while displaying past or coming weeks? When I tried to add a navigation controller for my game list page, I lost next and previous buttons.

P.S. The Game List is not a table view controller. I've added a table to a view controller.)

[image: Main.storyboard]

Answer (score 0):

From what it looks like you have the next and previous buttons going to the Games View Controller instead of the Tab Bar Controller. That might be your problem, that it's not going through the Tab Bar Controller, therefore not recognizing that there's supposed to be a tab bar. I would say to have it go through the Tab Bar Controller, but then it all depends on whether or not that tab is the default tab. Do you have any more information about the app you could give us? Like what's doing what?

Comment: Thank you for your answer mate. I solved it by using navigation controller again. Somewhere in my first time, I made a mistake which I couldn't find it again. Again thanks a lot.

Comment: No problem! Glad you got it figured out!